# use sklearn.cross_val_score on a simple equality

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using cross_val_score on a RandomForest :

```
scores=cross_val_score(rf,data,Y,cv=5)
scores.mean()
```

I would like to calculate the scores for a simple model where data is equal to a result in 2017 and Y the result in 2018. The model is simple :

```
data['result_2017'] = Y (= result_2018)
```

How to code this ?

```
    scores=cross_val_score(simple_model,data,Y,cv=5)
    scores.mean()
```

Comment: What is `simple_model`?

Comment: It's just : data['result_2017'] = Y (= result_2018)
I want to find a solution to use the same scoring method on a simple solution , which is not coded in sklearn.